# How do I conditionally add an attribute to a dynamic tag?

Tags: terraform

in config.meta file I store accesses to the google bigquery datasets. The `accesses` object is a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary contains the role as the first element and the second element element (e.g. `special_group` or `group_by_email`) which is being variated among the list.

My goal is to apply the accesses dynamically. The approach is pretty easy when each dictionary on the `accesses` list has the same second element (e.g. `special_group` only). **But how to apply them dynamically depends on the second element name/value?**

```
# config.meta file
{
    "accesses": [
        {
            "role": "OWNER",
            "special_group": "projectOwners"
        },
        {
            "role": "READER",
            "group_by_email": "myemail@myemail.com"
        },
       ...
    ]
    ...
}
```

terraform file:

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "dataset" {
    dataset_id    = "${var.dataset}"
    location      = "${var.bq_region}"
    friendly_name = "${var.dataset}"

    dynamic "access" {
        # get accesses (list of dictionaries) from a file
        for_each = [for a in jsondecode(file("$config.meta"))["access"]: {
            role = a.role
            special_group = a.special_group
            # how to get special_group/group_by name conditionally?
            # like: if dictionary has the key 'special_group' create that variable
            # othervise create 'group_by_name'
        }]

        content {
            role = access.value.role
            special_group = access.value.special_group
            # how to get special_group/group_by name conditionally?
            # like: if the 'special_group' had been declared add 'special_group' to the access block
            # othervise add 'group_by_name'.
        }
    }

}
```

How do I conditionally add an attribute to a dynamic tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
locals {
  items = fileexists("$config.meta") ? jsondecode(file("$config.meta")).accesses : []
  special_groups = [for v in local.items: v if lookup(v, "special_group", "") != ""]
  group_by_emails = [for v in local.items: v if lookup(v, "group_by_email", "") != ""]
}
```

You could use  multiple definitions of `dynamic` block

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "dataset" {

  ...

  dynamic "access" {
    for_each = [for a in local.special_groups: {
      role = lookup(a, "role", "")
      special_group = lookup(a, "special_group", "")
    }]

    content {
      role          = access.value.role
      special_group = access.value.special_group
    }
  }

  dynamic "access" {

    for_each = [for a in local.group_by_emails: {
      role = lookup(a, "role", "")
      group_by_email = lookup(a, "group_by_email", "")
    }]

    content {
      role           = access.value.role
      group_by_email = access.value.group_by_email
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: This will work, but creates added complexity. See Martin Atkins answer for a simpler solution and more complete explanation of the underlying mechanics.

Answer (score 3):

Inside a configuration block in Terraform, omitting an optional argument and setting that argument to `null` are equivalent. Because `access` is a nested block, we can exploit that to write expressions that conditionally set the argument.

```
  dynamic "access" {
    # get accesses (list of dictionaries) from a file
    for_each = [for a in jsondecode(file("$config.meta"))["access"]: {
      role           = a.role
      special_group  = try(a.special_group, null)
      group_by_email = try(a.group_by_email, null)
    }]

    content {
      role           = access.value.role
      special_group  = access.value.special_group
      group_by_email = access.value.group_by_email
    }
  }
```

This first uses [the `try` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/try.html) so that a missing attribute will result in falling back on a `null` value rather than an error. This means that the resulting objects will look something like this:

```
[
  {
    "role": "OWNER",
    "special_group": "projectOwners",
    "group_by_name": null,
  },
  {
    "role": "READER",
    "special_group": null,
    "group_by_email": "myemail@myemail.com",
  },
]
```

Inside the `content` block we then just assign all of these directly. The ones that are `null` will be treated by Terraform as if they are not set at all, due to the behavior I described earlier. (Notice that the behavior of treating `null` as unset doesn't apply when constructing object values: it is a special behavior only for direct arguments inside a block.)

This should then have the same effect as if you'd written out the following two `access` blocks directly:

```
access {
  role          = "OWNER"
  special_group = "projectOwners"
}

access {
  role           = "READER"
  group_by_email = "myemail@myemail.com"
}
```